# django 1.8 admin actions - how to automatically select all

Tags: python, django, action

I want to add a feature to download the filtered data on the admin page as a csv file.
What I want to achieve is to be able to download the filtered data without having to select them because it is tricky to select multiple pages of data.

Here is my code:

```
def download_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        # write to the response...

@admin.register(MyTable)
class MyTableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = (download_csv,)
    download_csv.short_description = 'Download as csv'

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        post = request.POST.copy()
        if admin.helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME not in post:
            post.update({admin.helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME:None})
            request._set_post(post)
        return super(VariantAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

The changelist_view code will suppress the validation that anything is selected.
The code above will download no data since queryset is empty.
I know I can implement the filter in my download_csv method using the POST parameters but that's high maintanance since anytime I want to add a filter, I have to update this.
Is there an easier way to select all filtered data?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you think it's tricky to select "multiple pages of data".

When you select all items on the current page (for example, via checkbox placed in table header) django offers you to "Select all" items across all pages. The link to do it is shown right after actions select.

Comment: I know, but I'm making the interface for non-techie people who cannot figure this out :)